# Problem with linking in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and I am creating a basic blog application.

When I have created a post it has an author. If you locate the author it displays a list of posts that have been created by that author, however when you select the post it is not linking to the post and is instead giving me the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PagesController#show

Couldn't find Page with ID=2

app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:8:in `show'

{"id"=>"2"}
```

My code in the Pages Controller is as follows:

```
def show #Show action
@page = Page.find(params[:id])
```

It looks as though when I select the link from the author menu it is not locating the correct page ID as it is routing to 2, 3, 4 etc, when the URL of the post is more like 28, 29, 30. If I locate the post in directly from the index menu the link to the post works fine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show your `link_to`?

Comment: What does your view look like? Specifically, what helpers are you using for your `link_to` on the posts/pages (and are you using those terms interchangeably)?

Comment: how did you define the route? show config/routes.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% @author.pages.each do |p| %>
  <%= link_to p.title, [[p.url]] %>
<% end %>
```

replace "[[p.url]]" with how you have your urls set up maybe

```
{:controller => 'pages', :action => 'show', :id => p.id}
```

Then format for your liking.

Comment: I have tried this and it is now linking to localhost:3000/authors/26 and I am getting: "error Couldn't find Author with ID=26". If I then manually change authors to pages it then finds the correct post for that author and is therefore linking correctly. How do I go about changing it so it directs to localhost:3000/pages/26?

Comment: It didn't work first time, but I have changed to => 'pages' and it worked perfectly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are passing a different object to the page_path parameter of the link to method on your authors page, below is an example of some erb for displaying a list of pages for an author and linking to them:

```
<ul>
  <% @author.pages.each do |page| %>
    <li><%= link_to page.title, page_path(page) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```